# SQL count by group

Tags: sql, oracle, count

I have to following schema

```
Movie(mvID, title, rating, year)
Director(directorID, firstname, lastname)
Genre(mvID*, genre)
Direct(mvID*, directorID*)
```

I need to know the director that directed to most movies of say the comedy genre and output their details with the count of how many movies they made in the that genre.

So I have

```
SELECT Director.DirectorID, Director.FirstName, Director.LastName, COUNT(*)
FROM Direct, Genre, Director
WHERE Direct.mvID = Genre.mvID
AND Genre.genre = 'Comedy'
AND Direct.DirectorID = Director.DirectorID
AND COUNT(*) > ALL
GROUP BY Director.DirectorID, Director.FirstName, Director.LastName
ORDER by COUNT(*) DESC
```

but I get a group function not allowed error.

Comment: I take it that Movie has a foreign key to Director?

Comment: using oracle
I have a direct relation
    Direct(mvID*, directorID*)

Comment: Your structure implies that a movie can have more than one director and more than one genre. Is that correct?

Answer (score 0):

The SQL below will solve your problem:

```
SELECT      Director.DirectorID, Director.FirstName, Director.LastName, COUNT(*)
FROM        Direct, Genre, Director
WHERE       Direct.mvID = Genre.mvID
AND     Genre.genre = 'Comedy'
AND     Direct.DirectorID = Director.DirectorID
AND     rownum = 1
GROUP BY    Director.DirectorID, Director.FirstName, Director.LastName
order by    COUNT(*) DESC
```

Specifically, this joins the tables and counts the movies directed by each director for movies of genre 'Comedy'. Then it sorts the row in descending order of count and grabs the first row.

Note you have two many<->many relationships so if you weren't only looking at comedy (i.e. if you ran this across multiple genres), you would probably have to use a different technique (i.e. multiple temp tables or similar virtual aggregates) in order to not have 'double counting in your SQL...

Also note that if two directors have the same count of movies for this genre, only one row would be brought back. You would have to modify the sql slightly if you wanted all directors with the same count of comedies to be returned.

Cheers,
Noah Wollowick

Comment: Thanks however this returns the Director with MVID 1 rather than the one with highest count of movies in the genre. I've add the > ALL clause but i get an error.

Answer (score 0):

```
select d.firstname,d.lastname,count(g.mvId)
from Director d
inner join Direct dr on d.directorId=dr.directorId
inner join Genre g on dr.mvId=g.mvId
where g.genre='comedy'
group by d.firstname
having count(g.mvId)=max(g.mvId)
```