# SQL Select Single most from a count - ALL opereator

Tags: sql, oracle

I have to following schema

```
Movie(mvID, title, rating, year)
Director(directorID, firstname, lastname)
Genre(mvID*, genre)
Direct(mvID*, directorID*)
```

I need to know the director that directed the **most** movies of say the comedy genre and output their details with the count of how many movies they made in the that genre.

So I have

```
SELECT Director.DirectorID, Director.FirstName, Director.LastName, COUNT(*)
FROM Direct, Genre, Director
WHERE Direct.mvID = Genre.mvID
AND Genre.genre = 'Comedy'
AND Direct.DirectorID = Director.DirectorID
AND COUNT(*) > ALL
GROUP BY Director.DirectorID, Director.FirstName, Director.LastName
```

but I get a group function not allowed error.

Comment: The SQL guide to oracle book uses the ALL operator this way, but i think i'm having trouble with the joining process

Comment: Resemble another question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19333776/sql-count-by-group

Answer (score 1):

First, get count by director and genre:

```
SELECT directorID, genre, COUNT(*) num_movies
FROM Movie JOIN Genre
ON Movie.mvID = Genre.mvID
JOIN Direct
ON Movie.mvID = Direct.mvID
GROUP BY directorID, genre
```

Now, rank the directors by genre:

```
SELECT
   directorID, genre,
   DENSE_RANK() OVER(PARTITION BY genre order by num_movies desc) rank
FROM
(SELECT directorID, genre, COUNT(*) num_movies
FROM Movie JOIN Genre
ON Movie.mvID = Genre.mvID
JOIN Direct
ON Movie.mvID = Direct.mvID
GROUP BY directorID, genre) X
```

Now, get top directors by genre:

```
SELECT directorID, genre
FROM (SELECT
   directorID, genre,
   DENSE_RANK() OVER(PARTITION BY genre order by num_movies desc) rank
   FROM
      (SELECT directorID, genre, COUNT(*) num_movies
       FROM Movie JOIN Genre
       ON Movie.mvID = Genre.mvID
       JOIN Direct
       ON Movie.mvID = Direct.mvID
       GROUP BY directorID, genre) )
WHERE rank=1
```

There is an alternative way using KEEP and FIRST but I personally find KEEP...FIRST/LAST syntax too confusing.

Answer (score 0):

This gives you a top list:

```
select * from (
SELECT Director.DirectorID, Director.FirstName, Director.LastName, COUNT(*)
FROM Direct, Genre, Director
WHERE Direct.mvID = Genre.mvID
AND Genre.genre = 'Comedy'
AND Direct.DirectorID = Director.DirectorID
GROUP BY Director.DirectorID, Director.FirstName, Director.LastName
ORDER BY COUNT(*) desc
) where rownum<2
```

(If this is what you would like to list.)

Comment: Thanks, was all cool to get the list, Just want the top director and the count.

Comment: I modified to return only the first row.

Comment: Thanks, that's great. Trying to get a grip on using ALL with multiple tables but this works well.